# Pass arguments to python based on wild character

Tags: python, bash, shell, wildcard

I have a shell script test.sh as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
ARG1=/bin/file1.txt
ARG2=/bin/testfile.txt
ARG3=/bin/samplefile.txt

test.py $ARG1 $ARG2 $ARG3
```

The python script reads the arguments and copies the files to another location. Instead of defining all the arguments separately as ARG1, ARG2, ARG3. I want to use a wild character as *.txt to define them and pass them to test.py.

I can't change the python file and all i can change is the test.sh file. So basically define the varaibles using *.txt and pass the arguments to test.py

I'm not much familiar with shell scripting. Is there a way I can save these variables in an array and then pass it to python script separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call

`test.py /bin/*.txt`

and bash will expand this to

`test.py /bin/file1.txt /bin/testfile.txt /bin/samplefile.txt`

To test shell expansions, you can use `echo`:

```
echo /bin/*.txt
```

or

```
echo /bin/newfile /bin/*.txt
```

which will then echo the list of files.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What if the test.py takes another argument which doesn't end with .txt

     test.py  /bin/newfile /bin/*.txt 
Will the above solution still work?

Comment: Yes. See my updated solution for how to easily test this.

Comment: When I test it on shell it is is working fine. But somehow my shell script is not allowing globbing. It still lits as *.txt and fails. Not sure what mistake I'm making. I'm calling the above code in a function in my shell script.